# No overload for method error on client server sockets application

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, .net-4.0, ipc

I am creating a client/server WPF application, where the server application adds new client information to a listview item if the client has not already connected, or updates that particular client's information OnDataReceived if they had already connected.  I'm getting the 'No overload for -- matches delegate -- error', but I am really not understanding why.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

By the way i'm pretty new to server/client socket communication, so if anyone can point me to some resources I would really appreciate it.

(updated with bkribbs answer)

```
// Error is here:
private void UpdateClientListControl()
{
    if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
       var lv = listBoxClientList;
       listBoxClientList.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new UpdateClientListCallback(UpdateClientList), new object[] { this.listBoxClientList, false, null });

       //No overload for 'UpdateClientList' matches delegate 'UpdateClientListCallback'
       //I think the error is in how i added these additional parameters, but I tried using 'bool AlreadyConnected' and 'ClientInfo CurrentClient' and
       //I get more errors 'Only assignment, call, incriment, ... can be used as a statement'

    }
    else
    {
        UpdateClientList(this.listBoxClientList);
    }
}
```

and

```
// This worked fine until I added bool Alreadyconnected and CurrentClient
void UpdateClientList(ListView lv, bool AlreadyConnected=false, ClientInfo CurrentClient = null)
    {
        if (AlreadyConnected)
        {
            //Updates listview with CurrentClient information that has changed
        }
        else
        {
            //Updates listview with new client information
        }
}
```

How I'm trying to use it in OnDataReceived:

```
public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
    //after receiving data and parsing message:
    if(recieved data indicates already connected)
    {
        UpdateClientList(this.listBoxClientList, true, clientInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        UpdateClientList(this.listBoxClientList);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. There are two problems.

The one you mention right now is because you haven't updated the delegate declaration for UpdateClientListCallback since you added two extra parameters.

Right now it looks like:

```
delegate void UpdateClientListCallback(ListView lvi);
```

You need to change it to:

```
delegate void UpdateClientListCallback(ListView lvi, bool AlreadyConnected, ClientInfo CurrentClient);
```

Your other problem that you would quickly discover is that you have the parameters a bit wrong. You are using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Deletegate, Object[])`

So to fix your problem replace:

```
listBoxClientList.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new UpdateClientListCallback(UpdateClientList), this.listBoxClientList, false, null);
```

with:

```
object[] parameters = new object[] { this.listBoxClientList, false, null };
listBoxClientList.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new UpdateClientListCallback(UpdateClientList), parameters);
```

or for a nice one liner:

```
listBoxClientList.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new UpdateClientListCallback(UpdateClientList), new object[] { this.listBoxClientList, false, null });
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm still getting the 'no overload for UpdateClientList matches delegate MainWindow.UpdateClientListCallback' error...

Comment: Where do you declare `listBoxClientList`? Is it a `ListView`?

Comment: In my xaml I have `<ListView x:Name="listBoxClientList"`, with a `GridView`. This had been working fine prior to adding extra arguments in `UpdateClientList`.  I was trying to find a way to update information on the client `ListView` `OnDataRecieved` if the client is already connected, rather than adding the client to the same list.  There must be a better way to do this?

Comment: Hm. Can I see the where you declare the `UpdateClientListCallback`?

Comment: oops... that was it.  Forgot to update UpdateClientListCallback.  Thanks @bkribbs!